# discord.py text to speech module?

Tags: python, discord.py

Are there any good modules for text to speech that i can use with discord.py. I was looking at pyttsx but from what I know you it transfers the text into an mp3, I would be able to play the mp3 file on discord.py but it would make things a little harder. Anyone know a better way?

**Other than discords built in /tts**

Comment: I don't know a lot about discord.py, but if the server enable tts why don't you just send `/tts text` in the channel you want (I guess discord.py allows you to send message in chat otherwise nevermind) ?

Answer (score 7):

You can send a message to any messageable using text-to-speech by passing `tts=True` to your `send` call:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot('!')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is a tts message", tts=True)

bot.run("token")
```

Your bot will need the [`send_tts_messages`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.send_tts_messages) permission.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has inbuilt text to speech, just send the message from the bot with `/tts [text_goes_here]`. Make sure it has TTS permissions enabled.

The only reason this wouldn't work is if you are wanting to make a bot that converts all text typed by users to be read aloud? (Sounds weird.) Although in that case use `pyttsx` which can read instantly or save as mp3.

`/tts` is the thing you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if it's possible to use pyttsx / pyttsx3 with Discord.py? I've tried but no luck.

Comment: @Persson Did you perchance find a solution?